# Deploying Java application via Java Web Start(.jnlp), directory permission and location?

Tags: java-web-start

In my jnlp file I need to use nativelib tag.

`<nativelib href="lib/windows/alib.dll"/>`

is that href refer to the directory on my server? what if my jar application looks for the alib.dll inside it's bin folder? how would I indicate this?

will there be any issues with write permission on where the application is installed (where is the default jnlp installation folder and how does the user change this?)